# larger train/val loss at initial epoch and slower decreasing compared to the paper's result

Tags: deep-learning, initialization, loss-function, reproducible-research

I am working on reproducing the results reported in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.01208). A UNET based network is used for estimating sound speed map from raw Ultrasound channel data. I have been stuck in further reducing the train/val loss for a long time.

Basically, I followed their methods of data simulation, preprocessing and used the same network architecture, hyperparameters (include kernel initializer, batch size, decay rate, etc.). The input size is 128*1024 rather than 192*2048 according to my ultrasound probe (based on their [recent paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-80432-9_11), the input size won't affect the performance).

So my question is do you have any suggestion to further investigate this problem based on your experience?

I attached my results (loss curves and images).
[RMSE loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVdMd.png)
[estimated sound speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D29X4.png)
And their results
[RMSE loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBSwy.png)
[estimated sound speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAHG0.png)
It seems my network failed to have a comparative convergence at the background, that could explain that I got a larger initial loss.

PS: Unfortunately, the paper didn't provide codes, so I have no clue to some details in terms of data simulation and training. I have contacted the author but hasn't got response yet.

The author mentioned somewhere instead of using a pixel-wise MSE, try a larger window size 3*3 or 5*5, I am not clear whether it is used for training or metric evaluation, any reference for the former?